# related rate problem how to solve?

Tags: calculus

[image]

The correct answers are there however I cant solve this myself. I've done other related rate problems just fine but the angle here has me lost.

I did it before but lost my notes and have a test comming up

I asumming tan(theta) = s/80 as the first related rate and can get the first derivitive to sec^2(theta)*dtheta/dt=1/80 * ds/dt

but not sure were to go from their

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be the first camera, $O$ the starting point, and $P$ the position of the dragster after two seconds. Then $\triangle COP$ is a right triangle, $|CO|=80$, and $|OP|=240$, where the lengths are measure in feet. Let $\theta(t)$ be the angle (in radians) through which the camera has turned $t$ seconds into the race; we know that $\theta(2)=\angle OCP$, and we’re told that $\theta'(2)=0.3\text{ rad}/\text{s}$.

Let $x(t)$ be the distance in feet that the dragster has travelled after $t$ seconds; we know that $x(2)=|OP|=240$, and we want $x'(2)$. Clearly we need to find a relationship between $x$ and $\theta$, so that we can apply our knowledge of $\theta'(2)$ to get $x'(2)$. The setup makes it clear that at time $t$ the points $C$ and $O$ and the position of the dragster are the vertices of a right triangle, so $$\tan\theta(t)=\frac{x(t)}{80}\;,$$ and $x(t)=80\tan\theta(t)$. Differentiating with respect to $t$, we get

$$x'(t)=80\sec^2\theta(t)\cdot\theta'(t)\;,$$

so $x'(2)=80(0.3)\sec^2\theta(2)=24\sec^2\theta(2)$. From $\triangle COP$ we see that $$\sec\theta=\frac{\sqrt{80^2+240^2}}{80}\;,$$ so

$$x'(2)=24\cdot\frac{80^2+240^2}{80^2}=240\;.$$

For (b) let $\varphi(t)$ be the angle through which the second camera has turned $t$ seconds into the race. Reasoning just as we did for the first camera, we see that

$$\tan\varphi(t)=\frac{x(t)}{120}\;,$$

since this camera is $120$ feet from the starting point at $O$, so $$x'(t)=120\sec^2\varphi(t)\cdot\varphi'(t)\;.$$ We know that $x'(2)=240$, so

$$\varphi'(2)=\frac{240}{120\sec^2\varphi(2)}=2\cos^2\varphi(2)=2\left(\frac{120}{\sqrt{120^2+240^2}}\right)^2=\frac{2\cdot120^2}{120^2+240^2}=0.4\;,$$

of course measured in rad/s.

Comment: @keith: You’re welcome.